# Unrecognized .sql File Type in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am following a Spring Boot tutorial in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition and have encountered an issue where my .sql files are not being recognized as SQL file types. Instead, they are being treated as generic text files or custom file types.

[files are not being recognized as SQL file types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkFtv.png)

An example of one of the files-

[An example of one of the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMx7C.png)

How the files look like in the tutorial I am watching-

[An example of the files in the tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIRJG.png)

*I am using PostgreSQL

I went to File Types in Settings, but was not able to find a solution
Also, I downloaded Database Navigator, but the type of the SQL is different.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html.